# Template argument deduction with multiple transformations

Tags: c++, templates, type-inference, type-traits, template-argument-deduction

I'm trying to write a generic function with an argument that contains multiple transformations on the template type, such as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template< typename _T_ >
void foo
(
     const std::basic_string< typename std::remove_cv< typename std::remove_extent< _T_ >::type >::type > & str
)
{
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}

int main( void )
{
    foo< char const [ 3 ] >( "abc" ); // OK
    foo( "abc" );                     // Cannot deduce template argument

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, the compiler is unable to deduce the correct type.
Tested with latest versions of Clang, GCC and MSVC.

Interestingly, it seems the compiler is able to infer with one transformation:

```
 const std::basic_string< typename std::remove_extent< _T_ >::type > & str
```

Obviously, the example above fails, because of the `const`, hence the need for `remove_cv` after `remove_extent`.

Is this expected, and is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: `_T_` is an identifier reserved to the C++ implementation in all contexts because it starts with an underscore followed by an upper case letter. Using such an identifier causes undefined behavior. I suggest you don't use it. (Just `T` is a commonly chosen template parameter name and would be fine here.)

Comment: I am not sure how you managed to get your alternative to deduce the type. `_T_` is still in a non-deduced context in that case and it should give the same error message.

Comment: Unrelated: `int main( void )` --> `int main()` - C++ is *not* C.

Comment: @walnut Correct, bad habits are hard to break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complicated names containing *qualified-id*s are *non-deduced contexts* in C++.  In

```
foo< char const [ 3 ] >( "abc" );
```

you supply the template argument `T`.  In

```
foo( "abc" );
```

the template argument `T` cannot be deduced (function arguments are separate from template arguments, so `T` will not be deduced from `"abc"`).

One solution is to deduce the template argument first and then construct the `basic_string` when the argument is a `const CharT*`:

```
template <class CharT>
void foo(const std::basic_string<CharT>& string)
{
    // ...
}

template <class CharT>
void foo(const CharT* p)
{
    std::basic_string<CharT> s{p};
    foo(s);
}
```

Another solution is to simply rely on class template argument deduction to handle both cases:

```
template <class Arg>
void foo(Arg&& arg)
{
    std::basic_string s{std::forward<Arg>(arg)};
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, `std::forward` is the best imho

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can build up the type in the template parameter list and take `T` as reference in the function parameter list

```
template<typename T, typename U = const std::basic_string<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_extent_t<T>>>>
void foo
(
  T& t // deducible context
)
{
  U& u = t;
  std::cout << u << std::endl;
}
```

<kbd>[Godbolt demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KiE4dr)</kbd>